# How can I use PSI/UAST on my Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, gradle-plugin

I am writing a Gradle plugin that should inspect some Kotlin files and report some data based on that inspection. I was planning to use UAST to perform the inspection, following what the Lint tool in Android does (https://github.com/JetBrains/uast and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lint-dev/7nLiXa04baM).
However, I cannot find a way, or any resources online, to add UAST, or even PSI, to my Gradle plugin. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure you need UAST for that? If you are processing only Kotlin files then you could just use Kotlin PSI.

Comment: I believe both of those could be valid, but the problem that I am facing is that those dependencies are not even available on the project, and I don't seem to be able to find anything that will let them import them as an external dependency...

Comment: I didn't get. You could add Kotlin compiler as a dependency `compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-compiler-embeddable', version: '1.2.41'` it is able to build a Kotlin PSI

Answer (score 3):

I recommend adding this to your repositories (the version are those atm - check out the newest versions [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.uast)):

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/uast/"}
}
```

and this to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  implementation "org.jetbrains.uast:uast-kotlin:1.0.10"
}
```

if your into MPP you can add:

```
  implementation "org.jetbrains.uast:uast-common:1.0.12"
  implementation "org.jetbrains.uast:uast-java:1.0.12"
```

**But don't forget UAST is still jvm-based, AFAIK**

There are also other tooling's for Testing and integrating it with Idea, for Intellij-plugins. The import's are also [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.uast)